# += operator overloaded, but use won't compile since it sees a simple + operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have overloaded both the + and += operator, with the following signatures:

```
// within A's header file..
A operator+(const B &p);    
A &operator+=(B &p);
```

Why is it that when I try to use the += operator, I get the compiler error message

> Invalid operands of types "A*" and
>   "B*" to binary 'operator+'.

```
an_a; // an instance of class A
B *a_b = new B(some_parameters);
an_a += a_b;
```

Answer (score 5):

You overloaded the operator for `B&`. You're trying to pass it a pointer, not an instance of B or reference to B. The following should compile: `an_a += *a_b;`, although a more likely fix is:

```
A an_a(some parameters);
B a_b(some parameters);
an_a += a_b;
```

Also beware that dynamic allocation and arithmetic operator overloading don't play especially nicely together. If it's only the inputs that are dynamically allocated it's probably fine. Just don't try to allocate the *result* with `new` and return it as a pointer, or you'll find that in order to avoid memory leaks the calling code can't use any of the simple expressions that were the reason you wanted operator overloading in the first place.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that your reported error message disagrees with your code snippet. The comment in the code claims that `an_a` is an instance of class A, but the error messages claims that it isn't, it's a pointer. You can't overload `operator+=` for pointers on both sides, so if both operands are pointers then I think `p1 += p2` always just means `p1 = p1 + p2`.

Comment: ... or anyway, neither `p1 += p2` not `p1 = p1 + p2` is valid, and you can't make them valid with operator overloads. I don't know why the compiler complains in this particular way, though, rather than complaining about the failed match with `operator+=`.

Comment: if an_a is a pointer, you can try dereferencing both: `*an_a += *a_b;`

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is inconsistent with the comments in your code. It looks like both `an_a` and `a_b` are pointers, so you have to dereference them to use operators: `*an_a += *a_b;`.

Also note that your `operator+=` takes `B` by non-const reference. If you're changing the right-hand argument to that operator someone is going to be very surprised and unhappy sometime. Make it `const` reference instead.

Comment: "very surprised and unhappy ", good catch, and for the same reason `operator+` should take a const LHS. So if it's defined as a member function, `A operator+(const B&) const;`